# Cannot get flash video websites (YouTube, etc.) to work

Tags: firefox, video, google-chrome, flash

I know that other, multiple questions have been posted on this, but I'm fairly certain I've applied most, if not all, of the suggested solutions, and I'm no closer to resolving this issue.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 (Black Opal, 32-bit system, Firefox web browser), and I cannot use any website that provides flash video (e.g., YouTube).  The page loads, but the typical black box with the "play" icon does not load...that area is completely white/blank.  This is true of all other Flash sites.

I made sure I have the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package installed, and I even tried installing the `flashplugin-installer` ... in fact, according to Synaptic Package Manager, I have that AND `flashplugin-downloader` installed.  Interestingly, I also have `adobe-flashplugin` version 11.2.202.350, which would seem to be correct (I know that support for Flash in Linux ended with 11.2) and both `adobe-flash-properties-gtk` and `-kde` (whatever those are).  Also, it appears that none of the previous Firefox `helper-extensions` for flash in Linux are available any longer.  I have no idea where to go from here, and being able to see flash websites is occasionally a necessity for me.

As an interesting related note: Google Chrome/Chromium (I can't remember which) was installed as part of my Ubuntu system install, and I **seem** to remember it working...until I installed the `flashplugin-installer` to try and fix my problems with flash...now, Chrome doesn't even load!  Double-clicking on the icon produces no response.  Looking in the system monitor, I can see instances of Google Chrome are invoked when I double-click the icon, but there is no visible effect (no browser window, etc.)

Running Google Chrome from terminal shows:

```
[0428/183027:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(236)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox! Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly.
```

At the same time, I got a popup window that told me `System Problem has been detected` (or something to that effect) and asked if I wanted to report it, etc, etc.

What did I do wrong, or what am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The last Flash version provided by Ubuntu repos is 11.2.

To get latest Flash version 13, the easiest way is hrough Google Chrome browser.

Unfortunately the Pepper Flash Plugin of Chrome doesn't work with the default Ubuntu browser, Firefox.

You should reinstall Google Chrome:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall google-chrome
```

You may uninstall the old `flashplugin-installer` because it is obsolete.

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Cornelius.  Unfortunately, this did not work.  After the reinstall, Chrome behaves exactly as it did before:  double clicking on it will create an instance in System Monitor (as well as an instance of "chrome-sandbox"), but there is no visible effect  (Also, I got rid of "flashplugin-installer").  I'm really not looking to upgrade to Flash version 13:  version 11.2 is just fine with me; I simply can't get it to work at all!

Comment: @Superion Seems like this issue is specific to Athlon XP processors https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=318646 and http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/5EmprHC36WU . What processor do you have?

Comment: Hello @Cornelius.  I was able to find some of the same information you found.  I did some research and found I DO have an AMD Athlon processor...model 2800+ (estimated).  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a solution.  One poster in a forum mentioned, "Oh, well, back to Firefox"...but I cannot get flash to work with that, either!

Comment: At this point, based on my research and other threads, I've even tried using an older version of Flash's _libplayer.so_ file, placed in _usr/lib/mozilla/plugins_ (or something like that)...that solution also failed.  Does anyone else have any input?  I'm running out of options, and this is a critical feature for me..._surely_ Linux/Ubuntu has some way of doing this!

Comment: Hello @Cornelius: do you or anyone else have any additional input or suggestions?  I have not been able to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Only this plugin did the trick !

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.